# How can I retrieve the value of the "Property" attribute of an NUnit Test Method using System.Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, system.reflection

```
I have an NUnit test method which looks like this

        [Test]
        [Property("TestDescription", "Testing Subtraction of Two numbers")]
        [NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute("mytag,subtract")]
        public void TestSubtract()
        {
            int res = SimpleCalculator.Subtract(10,10);
            //some lines of code....

        }
```

I am reading the attribute of this method using System.Reflection in C#. But, I have not been able to read the value of the "Property" attribute which is "TestDescription", "Testing Subtraction of Two numbers". I also need to read the value of the CategoryAttribute. So far I have not been able to read the values. Please help me on this.

This is my code below. I am loading the assembly from a dll.
 Then, loading all the types. For each types I am retrieving the methodInfo.
 For each methodInfo I am retrieving the attributes. After retrieving the
 "NUnit.Framework.PropertyAttribute". I need retrieve its value.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
var types = a.GetTypes();                                
foreach(Type type in types)
{                                     
  foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in type.GetMethods())
  {
       var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        foreach (var attr in attributes)
        {
         if ((attr.ToString() == "NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute") || (attr.ToString() == 
                                                  "NUnit.Framework.TestCaseAttribute"))
          {
                     //some code

          }
         else if((attr.ToString() == "NUnit.Framework.PropertyAttribute"))
         {
               //** need to retrieve the attribute value here.
         }

       }
   } 
}
```

Comment: I have to wonder why you are doing this, rather than letting NUnit itself do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes` to get all information. `PropertyAttribute` is a little bit tricky, because you can have multiple values assigned to one key. Here is an example:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dllPath = @"C:\Path\To\MyDll.dll";

            Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
            Type[] types = a.GetTypes();

            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in type.GetMethods())
                {
                    PropertyAttribute[] propertyAttributes = (PropertyAttribute[])Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(methodInfo, typeof(PropertyAttribute));

                    foreach (PropertyAttribute attribute in propertyAttributes)
                        foreach (string key in attribute.Properties.Keys)
                            foreach (var value in attribute.Properties[key])
                                Console.WriteLine($"PropertyAttribute :: Key: {key} :: Value: {value}");

                    CategoryAttribute[] categoryAttributes = (CategoryAttribute[])Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(methodInfo, typeof(CategoryAttribute));

                    foreach (CategoryAttribute attribute in categoryAttributes)
                        Console.WriteLine($"CategoryAttribute :: Name: {attribute.Name}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I am getting the expected result :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use NUnit test context?

You will be able to get all needed data and information about the test.

See NUnit docs [here](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext).